# npm run build fails node:internal/fs/utils:348 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm, build, enoent, node.js-fs

[image]
Running *npm run build*  command fails with the error as shown in the screenshot.

As it may be seen from the following images, the file does exist.

[image]
[image]

Here is the version info

```
node v14.17.6
npm 9.1.3
Mac OS 12.5.1 (Monterey)
vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0
vue: "^2.6.14
```

None of the solutions out there seem to work. *npm run serve* command works fine and it compiles successfully. However, *npm run build* runs into this issue.

I have tried deleting *node_modules*, *package-lock.json*, update *node*, *npm*, deleting  */usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm* folders. This error somehow has been persistent.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not a expert or anything but all i can see is that you are doing something from a file like importing a function or variable but that file does not exist try checking the spelling of the file or go to to location of the file to confirm that the file is there (again speaking i'm not a expert)

Comment: I checked. That's what baffles me. The file does exist. See the updated screenshots.

Comment: Hi @manpreet, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the time to edit your answers to use proper sentences, with punctuation and capitalization. This will make them more readable for your pairs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix it
[image]

Since I attempted different things, I am not sure as to what exactly fixed it. But I will write the commands and code I have used below in case it helps someone else

Current version info

```
node v18.12.1
npm 8.19.2
```

Commands executed (not sure of the order now)

---

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass
npm rebuild
npm rebuild sass
npm i sass
npm i node-sass
```

---

```
sudo npm install -g n
nvm use node && npm update --global npm
npm cache clean
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
npm audit fix
npm audit fix --force
```

---

delete **node_modeules** and **package-lock.json**
reinstall **npm**

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm package-lock.json
npm i
```

---

```
 export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

---

uninstall **core-js**

---

Install core-js

```
npm i core-js
```

---

changed vue/cli-plugin-babel version to 5.0.0

```
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.0",
```

---

```
npm i webpack --save

npm i --save node-polyfill-webpack-plugin
```

---

Here is the old **vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    apollo: {
      enableMocks: true,
      enableEngine: true
    }
  }
}
```

---

Here is the new **vue.config.js**

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    apollo: {
      enableMocks: true,
      enableEngine: true,
    },
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    performance: {
      hints: false,
    },
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.performance.maxEntrypointSize(400000).maxAssetSize(400000);
    new NodePolyfillPlugin();
  },
};
```

Inputs from various resources were used to resolve the issue. **node_modules** folder was deleted several times and `npm i` command was executed the same number of times. Hope this helps.